# Can virtual function be private in Python

Tags: python

I want need a virtual mechanism in Python and was implemented as below:

```
class A() :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.level()

    def level(self) :
        print("At level A")

class B(A)
    def level(self) :
        print("At level B")
```

It worked as expected:

```
>>>b = B()
At level B
```

Then I wanted to keep level() function in private by changing function's name into __level():

```
class A() :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.__level()

    def __level(self) :
        print("At level A")

class B(A)
    def __level(self) :
        print("At level B")
```

But it didn't work:

```
>>>b = B() 
At level A
```

The virtual mechanism magically lost when the function became private! Can someone help to explain why?

Comment: Use a single underscore to indicate "private." Two invokes [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

Comment: @kindall But name mangling is exactly what makes the method private.

Comment: In any case, the fact that the name is mangled is why the method isn't being called.

Answer (score 1):

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling.

[Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)

```
class A() :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.__level()
        self._B__level()

    def __level(self) :
        print("At level A")

class B(A):
    def __level(self) :
        print("At level B")

In [228]: b=B()
At level A
At level B
```

Due to this mangling, the B version of `__level` can't be used from `A` methods (even if they are inherited by a `B` object).  It has to use the mangled name explicitly.  Breaking this 'virtual' function link (as you call it) is the purpose of mangling, as stated in the above clip.

```
In [232]: b._A__level()
At level A
In [233]: b._B__level()
At level B
In [234]: b.__level()
....
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '__level'
```

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj for patient explanation and example. The example leads to the philosophy of Python. There is probably no real **private** because we could still be able to access **private** by 'myclass._myclass_private'. Anything involving in the philosophy of a language, there is no right/wrong. Just have to adapt into it.